# VLookup Loop not working

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying VLookup until the cells in Column A are empty and it is not working and is returning Run-time error '1004' Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class. Any help? Or is there a better loop that I can use.

```
Sub FindOldValue()
Dim oldvalue As String
Dim result As String
i = 2
j = 1
K = 2
l = 3

Do

oldvalue = Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, j) & Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, K) & "delete"
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(oldvalue, Worksheets("Raw Delta").Range("A:H"), 7, 0)
Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, l) = result
i = i + 1
j = j + 1
K = K + 1

Loop Until Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, 1) = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use formula for this simple task?

Comment: Tried it. But because its a large file and it's taking some time to loop in just 200 items. What more if its a 1000. Haha

Comment: What version of Excel is this (2007, 2013, etc)? Also, would writing your own lookup function be acceptable? You could make a function to do this with a just few lines of code.

Comment: 1000 is not a lot. You can mass change FormulaR1C1 without loops.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using only Application.Vlookup instead of Application.Worksheetfunction.vlookup in the line

```
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(oldvalue, Worksheets("Raw Delta").Range("A:H"), 7, 0)
```

?

How about changing the loop to something like this?

```
Do

oldvalue = Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, j) & Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, K) & "delete"
resultrow = Application.Match(oldvalue, Worksheets("Raw Delta").Columns(1), 0)
If Not IsError(resultrow) Then
    Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, l) = Worksheets("Raw Delta").Cells(resultrow,7).Value
End If
i = i + 1
j = j + 1
K = K + 1

Loop Until Worksheets("Products").Cells(i, 1) = ""
```

Comment: Tried it but it's too slow

Comment: still having the same issue

Comment: Are you using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to speed things up a little? (and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` once you've finished)